# How to access scope in a function inside link function in angularjs directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

This might not be an angularJS problem but I am at my wit's end here. The code is shown below:

```
prep.directive('resultgraph', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',

    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        //** scope accessible here **

        DomReady.ready(function () {
            ThreeBox.preload([
                '/scripts/lib/snippets.glsl.html',
            ], function () {

               //....scope not accessible here
```

How do I access the scope inside the callback function of 'preload', where it says scope is not accessible here ?

Comment: what do you get when you try to access it?

Answer (score 0):

If you need the DOM to be ready you can do this inside the link function (the scope will be accessible):

```
$timeout(function(){
    alert('DOM ready');
    //** scope accessible here **
});
```