# Access scope in function within link function

Tags: jquery, angularjs

If I have a function within my link function, how can I access scope variables? It seems to work fine in the main link function, but once I try to make another function in link (for example, to make use of JQLite), I can't access the scope anymore.

```
.directive('myDir', function() {
    return {
       restrict: 'E',
       templateUrl: 'myURL',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //scope accessible here
            scope.dothis = function() {
               scope.message = "I can see the scope!"
            };

            var myDiv = element.find('div')

            myDiv.on('click', function() {
                //scope not accessible here!
                scope.message = "I won't change message because I see no scope."
            };
         };
     };
   });
```

Things I have tried:

1. Making the function I want a variable itself, eg

   ```
   var func = function() {scope.message = "Hello"}
   ```

   and then the JQLite code

   ```
   myDiv.on('click', func)
   ```

   But I can't tell if that's not working because scope isn't defined, or for some other reason.
2. Making the function I want a scope variable, eg

   ```
   scope.func = function() {scope.message = "Hello"}
   myDiv.on('click', scope.func())
   ```

   But (and this is the weird bit) in this case it just executes the function, without waiting for myDiv to be clicked.
3. Googling. I found an old stackoverflow question without any good answers :(
   ([How to access scope in a function inside link function in angularjs directive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27920293/how-to-access-scope-in-a-function-inside-link-function-in-angularjs-directive))

And now I'm stuck. Can anyone offer guidance? Is this just a fact of AngularJS, with no workarounds?

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN what would be helpful? The HTML calling this directive or the HTML in templateUrl?

Comment: Events added via jqLite / jQuery don't trigger a digest. Run `scope.$apply()` at the end of your event handler. Other than that, your code looks ok

Comment: both templateURl html and your div

Comment: Your #2 reference won't work. It should have been `myDiv.on('click', scope.func)`. Even then you would still need to manually trigger a digest though.

Comment: Also show me dothis function

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) ~ *"`$apply()` is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of the angular framework. (For example from **browser DOM events**, setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries)"*

Comment: @Phil Thanks, that was the problem!! I read all about scope.$apply() but I still didn't understand when to actually use it, apparently.

Comment: The good thing about running it at the wrong time / place is that it will throw an error at you ;)

Comment: you could simply bind the click on the element from the directive elem.bind('click', function(){ // do smth});